# Looking up values from a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have 2 dataframes that I want to combine. The first one looks as follows:

```
    Date        HomeTeam      AwayTeam
0   06/01/14    Real Madrid   Celta Vigo
1   06/01/14    Celta Vigo    Valencia
```

And a second one that looks like this:

```
    EVENT_ID    HomeTeam        AwayTeam    SELECTION   ODDS
0   112324699   Real Madrid     Celta Vigo  Celta Vigo  47.50
1   112324699   Real Madrid     Celta Vigo  Real Madrid 1.13
2   112324699   Real Madrid     Celta Vigo  The Draw    16.00
3   112369682   Celta Vigo      Valencia    Celta Vigo  3.30
4   112369682   Celta Vigo      Valencia    The Draw    3.55
5   112369682   Celta Vigo      Valencia    Valencia    2.43
```

So basically in the second dataframe one match has 3 rows, one each for either team and one for the draw (SELECTION) with its corresponding odds (ODDS).

What I want to do now is add the information about the odds from the second dataframe to the first dataframe, so I want to end up with the following:

```
    Date        HomeTeam      AwayTeam    OddsHome    OddsDraw    OddsAway
0   06/01/14    Real Madrid   Celta Vigo  1.13        16.00       47.50
1   06/01/14    Celta Vigo    Valencia    3.30        3.55        2.43
```

I tried to write and apply a lookup function, but failed miserably.
Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution :

```
df2=df2.merge(df1,on=['HomeTeam','AwayTeam'],how='left')
df2['SELECTION']=df2.groupby('EVENT_ID').apply(lambda x : x.SELECTION.replace({x.HomeTeam.values[0]:'Home',x.AwayTeam.values[0]:'Away'})).values
df2.set_index(['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','Date','SELECTION']).ODDS.unstack().reset_index()
Out[1151]: 
SELECTION    HomeTeam   AwayTeam      Date   Away  Home  TheDraw
0           CeltaVigo   Valencia  06/01/14   2.43  3.30     3.55
1          RealMadrid  CeltaVigo  06/01/14  47.50  1.13    16.00
```

Answer (score 3):

I would reshape df2 into new_df2 to look like this

```
df2['SELECTION'] = np.where(df2['SELECTION'] == df2['HomeTeam'], 'Home', np.where(df2['SELECTION'] == df2['AwayTeam'],'Away', 'Draw'))

new_df2 = df2.set_index(['EVENT_ID','HomeTeam','AwayTeam','SELECTION']).unstack().reset_index()
new_df2.columns = new_df2.columns.map(''.join)

    EVENT_ID    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    ODDSAway    ODDSDraw    ODDSHome
0   112324699   Real Madrid Celta Vigo  47.50       16.00       1.13
1   112369682   Celta Vigo  Valencia    2.43        3.55        3.30
```

Now use merge

```
df1.merge(new_df2, on = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']).drop('EVENT_ID', axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    Date        HomeTeam    AwayTeam    ODDSAway    ODDSDraw    ODDSHome
0   06/01/14    Real Madrid Celta Vigo  47.50       16.00       1.13
1   06/01/14    Celta Vigo  Valencia    2.43        3.55        3.30
```